# Joda Time on android causing IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, jodatime, android-jodatime

Description: The following method is supposed to get the date of the last inventory count from Firestore, and execute **proceedWithInventoryMode()** if it's been at least 24 hours.

```
private void checkIf24HourReached() {
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    LocalDateTime _24hrsBefore = now.minusDays(1);

    db.collection("Project").document(Prefs.getString("ManageID",
            GlobalObject._FIRESTORE_ID))
            .collection("inventoryMode")
            .document(GlobalObject._INVENTORY_MODE_DATA_ID)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> {
                String lastInventoryEndDate = documentSnapshot.getString("date");
                Log.d("lastInventoryEndDate: ", lastInventoryEndDate);
                if (lastInventoryEndDate == null) {
                    proceedWithInventoryMode();
                } else {
                    if (lastInventoryEndDate.isEmpty()) {
                        proceedWithInventoryMode();
                    }
                    LocalDateTime lastInventoryDate = new LocalDateTime(lastInventoryEndDate);
                    if (_24hrsBefore.isAfter(lastInventoryDate)) {
                        proceedWithInventoryMode();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                                "Last Inventory ended less than a day ago.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                                "Last date: " + lastInventoryEndDate,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                    "Date couldn't be read.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());

}
```

Problem: I'm getting an *IllegalArgumentException*. The Log statement in the **onSuccess()** statement prints: "lastInventoryEndDate:: 13/07/2022 09:57:11". But the error log is as follows:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.nati.mvp.flowiusmanage, PID: 18644
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "13/07/2022 09:57:11" is malformed at "/07/2022 09:57:11"
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket.doParseMillis(DateTimeParserBucket.java:187)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseMillis(DateTimeFormatter.java:826)
    at org.joda.time.convert.StringConverter.getPartialValues(StringConverter.java:87)
    at org.joda.time.LocalDateTime.<init>(LocalDateTime.java:414)
    at org.joda.time.LocalDateTime.<init>(LocalDateTime.java:358)
    at com.nati.mvp.flowiusmanage.fragments.inventoryFragments.InventoryModeFragment.lambda$checkIf24HourReached$2$InventoryModeFragment(InventoryModeFragment.java:157)
    at com.nati.mvp.flowiusmanage.fragments.inventoryFragments.-$$Lambda$InventoryModeFragment$_kMo6tPuE8p1PpNkIRJgZvJYet8.onSuccess(Unknown Source:6)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzm.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7581)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)
```

Any idea how I can solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You didn’t include the code which does the actual parsing but I’m assuming its got something to do with your date not being in ISO8601 format. You’ll have to supply a custom formatter that will be used to parse the string into an appropriate date and time object.

In your case, you can create a custom formatter

`val formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(“dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss”)`

And use it to parse your date

`val dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, formatter);`

Comment: I think the parsing is implicit in the line `LocalDateTime lastInventoryDate = new LocalDateTime(lastInventoryEndDate);` where `lastInventoryEndDate` is a `String` with value `13/07/2022 09:57:11`. The good solution would be store the last date and time in the ISO 8601 format that `LocalDateTime` expects.

Comment: @OleV.V. The implicit parsing only works when your date is properly formatted in ISO8601. If not then it will fail without a custom formatter.

Comment: Exactly. Your answer is to the point except you want upper case `MM` for month in the format pattern string.